# Update field in table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table `PNLReference`

```
 PnlId  LineTotalisationId  Designation TypeTotalisation    Totalisation
1   A   Gross Fees  Formule A01+A02+A03+A04+A05
2   A01 GF1 Comptes imputables  975800|758000|706900|706000|706430|706420|706410|706400|706530|706520|706510|706001|706401|706431|706531|706902
3   A02 GF2 Comptes imputables  706500|709400|706130|706120|706110|706100|706830|706820|706810|706800|706730|706720|706710|706700|706330|706101|706131|706331|706501|706701|706801|706831|709401|706731
```

I have filled table DimPNL as following

```
INSERT [dbo].[DimPNL] (
PNLCode
,PNLName
,PNLParentId
,Operator
)
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(255)') AS PNLCode
    ,Ref.Designation AS PNLName
    ,split.LineTotalisationId AS PNLParentId
    ,split.Operator AS Operator
FROM (
    SELECT tbl.Designation
        ,tbl.LineTotalisationId
        ,tbl.TypeTotalisation
        ,tbl.PnlId
        ,tbl.Totalisation
        ,CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(tbl.Totalisation, tbl.Operator, '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML) x
        ,tbl.Operator
    FROM ##TTResults AS tbl
    ) split
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PNLReference] Ref
    ON Ref.LineTotalisationId = t.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(255)')
) Result
```

table dimpnl contents a filed sign which have to be filled like that : if all numbers in Totalisation in table PNLReference starts with 7 the sign would be -1 else sign will be 1.How to do it ? any idea ?

Comment: `CASE WHEN LEFT(PNLParentId,1)='7' then -1 else 1 END [SIGN]` assuming im following Totalisation properly.

Comment: @DanielE. I 've just edited my question , It must be for all numbers in Totalisation  .

Comment: You need to use that case in the nested select and take MAX(sign), if it stays -1 then they all started with 7...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CASE WHEN LEFT(Totalisation,1)='7' then -1 else 1 END [SIGN]` will give you a field that you can take the `MAX(sign)`, if it stays -1 then they all started with 7